# How to make a custom list in html with customized indices?

Tags: html, css

How to make a list like:
Item 1: Mango
Item 2: Orange
Item 3: Papaya
Item 4: Avocado
in HTML?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. As you're new to the site, I'd suggest reading the guidelines on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) section of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***Ordered List*** here as below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<ol>
  <li>Mango</li>
  <li>Orange</li>
  <li>Papaya</li>
   <li>Avocado</li>
</ol>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ishtiyaq qureshi If you got the answer please consider giving it a tick mark ✔ it would be much appreciated.